# I have an issue with chat.stackoverflow, In every room other than NSChat room, it is showing me that i need 20 reputation to chat

Tags: support

I have an issue while opening other chat rooms like ' cocos2d' and 'iPhone/iPad'. I already have reputation 420.

[image]

I can access [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat) just fine, but all other rooms tell me I don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: The avatar looks different from the one you have here.  Are you sure you're signed in?

Comment: Note, refreshing information from the parent site for this user (yes, logged in under the [same account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/735868/) as the avatar shows) fails. I requested that @Nirav open a bug report.

Comment: I am using the same account for both sites, stack and meta, i don't know how is my avatar changed.

Comment: @Nirav The OpenID is the same for both accounts, but the e-mail is different on your MSO and SO accounts.

Comment: Oh! ok, i think i have forgotten about it. issue solved. thanks buddy.

Comment: @Nirav I'm leaving this open for a dev to take a look at, I don't want to disclose your account details, but I'd like one to have a look. What happened shouldn't have happened, at least as far as I understand things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should work now. This was a consequence of the combination of your suspension and of your sock puppet user being merged. Chat sometimes doesn't handle that gracefully without manual intervention.

Comment: balpha thank you very much.

Comment: LOL@the answer...`this was a consequence of the combination of your suspension and of your sock puppet...` wonder if OP really wanted to ask this question.