# Unable to chat. Can you help, please?

Tags: support, chat

In this thread, [How do I pronounce the name "Aurelius"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206495/how-do-i-pronounce-the-name-aurelius/206498#206498), I followed up a suggestion to continue the discussion in chat, and posted my comment here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18444/discussion-between-tunny-and-fumblefingers. Two people have now posted comments there, but I cannot. In the place at the bottom of the page where I imagine I should be able to write my post is the apparently irremovable message:"You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq. " I have followed up a suggestion from Matt to log in to the chatroom, following a link provided by him, and also clicked on everything I could see on the chat page, but I am still unable to post anything.

Comment: Was your account ever merged with another? That's the usual cause, where there are two chat server profiles that were not merged and one of them doesn't have enough reputation.

Comment: I don't know that any of my accounts have been merged. On all the StackExchange sites I subscribe to, my reputation is well above 20.

Comment: It looks like you're logged in to chat as http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/131580 (presumably someone else using the same computer?) who indeed only has 1 reputation. Please go to http://chat.stackexchange.com/logout and click the button there. Once you've logged out, go to http://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login, which should log you in to chat as the correct user.

Comment: Yes, I checked that first. :-) It is the most common reason for the problems you are experiencing, see [Unable to log in to chat.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158548) and [I have an issue with chat.stackoverflow, In every room other than NSChat room, it is showing me that i need 20 reputation to chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152194), for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There's no merge involved here. Those also rarely cause problems on chat.se, that's more of a problem on chat.so.

Comment: @balpha: I saw your comment indeed; interesting that the merge problems are limited to chat.so only.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's related to the fact that chat.so has the same user ids as SO itself, that means it's less flexible with solving those problems fully automatically.

Comment: Thanks to you  all. I am not quite sure which action it was that cured the problem, but I can now chat.